# certbot-auto: Client lacks sufficient authorization

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, certbot

I know this question has been asked several times, but I need some specific help as I've been taking advice from several other threads and nothing has worked to this point.

I'm trying to renew my SSL certificate in Ubuntu 14.04 using `certbot-auto renew`, and I'm running an Apache2 server and nginx.  I'm getting the following output for `certbot-auto renew`:

```
  root@PostgreSQLServer:/# sudo certbot-auto renew
  Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/my-domain.com.conf
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
  Renewing an existing certificate
  Performing the following challenges:
  http-01 challenge for my-domain.com
  Waiting for verification...
  Cleaning up challenges
  Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/my-domain.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. my-domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://my-domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ailNmgZADpb4QBipKM57sOi9w3PwNkwBwVFiRYs7i40: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Not Found</h1>
  <p". Skipping.

  All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
  1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

  IMPORTANT NOTES:
   - The following errors were reported by the server:

     Domain: my-domain.com
     Type:   unauthorized
     Detail: Invalid response from
     http://my-domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ailNmgZADpb4QBipKM57sOi9w3PwNkwBwVFiRYs7i40:
     "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
     <html><head>
     <title>404 Not Found</title>
     </head><body>
     <h1>Not Found</h1>
     <p"

     To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
     entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
     contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I ensured the `.well-known` folder exists in `/var/www/my-domain.com/public_html` and when I navigate to `http://my-domain.com/.well-known/` in my browser, I am able to see the contents of that directory.  I also added an `acme-challenge` folder in `.well-known` and included a `test.txt` file for testing; I was able to access the directory and the text file in my browser.

I found that the `acme-challenge` folder was not created when I ran the `certbot-auto` command so it seems to be a permissions issue.  I am running `certbot-auto` as root, but also gave write permissions to `www-data` user on the `.well-known` and `acme-challenge` folders (root and www-data users are running the apache2 and nginx processes).

Even after granting that write permission, I still get the 404 error detailed above.

I also have an automated cert renewal process running via `crontab` and I have the output being logged to a local file.  In that log file, I see the renewal request seemed to be working correctly until `certbot-auto` was upgraded from 0.9.3 to 0.10.1.  Here's a sample from the log file when the upgrade took place:

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/offensively-bad.com.conf
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/offensively-bad.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
  No renewals were attempted.

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/offensively-bad.com.conf
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/offensively-bad.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
  No renewals were attempted.
  Upgrading certbot-auto 0.9.3 to 0.10.1...
  Replacing certbot-auto...
  Creating virtual environment...
  Installing Python packages...
  Installation succeeded.

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/offensively-bad.com.conf
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/offensively-bad.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
  IMPORTANT NOTES:
   - The following errors were reported by the server:

     Domain: offensively-bad.com
     Type:   unauthorized
     Detail: Invalid response from
     http://offensively-bad.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/tkSc8l-r1XVPIF5TosTbEXiYMa8sQnoXEjAEgAwRoqI:
     "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
     <html><head>
     <title>404 Not Found</title>
     </head><body>
     <h1>Not Found</h1>
     <p"

     To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
     entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
     contain(s) the right IP address.
```

You can see that after upgrading, the process began failing with a 404 message.

I've tried all the advice I could find online and am completely stumped, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My problem was a too old certbot version on my raspberry pi raspbian Stretch:

```
certbot --version
```

Gave

> certbot 0.10.2

```
apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t stretch-backports
```

Did the trick:

> certbot 0.21.1

And then just

> certbot --apache -d domain.com

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit this conf file: `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/offensively-bad.com.conf` and modify the line below `[[webroot_map]]`:

```
[[webroot_map]]
offensively-bad.com = /path/to/what/certbot/thinks/is/the/correct/webroot/path/initially/specified/by/the/user
```

In my case, I changed it to

```
    offensively-bad.com = /var/www/offensively-bad.com/public_html/
```

Thanks to the forum at letsencrypt for helping me out.